# Calling em.merge repeatedly from async method locks database table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions

I'm using the Java Persistence API in JBoss/Wildfly 7.1 to interface with a MSSQL database. I have a long running asynchronous function that regularly inserts and updates into a table but has a few seconds between each update. While this function is running the table becomes locked in a transaction and I'm unable to query the table from within or outside of the Java application. Below is an example of how I am implementing my DAO:

```
@Stateless
class Dao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void mergeEntity(Entity e){
        em.merge(e);
    }

    public Entity getEntity(int id){
        return em.find(Entity.class,id);
    }
}

class Service {

    @Inject
    private Dao dao;

    private void updateEntity(int id){
        Entity e = dao.getEntity(id)
        //do update logic
        dao.mergeEntity(e);
    }
}
```

I've also tried requesting a new transaction for the `mergeEntity` method:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void mergeEntity(Entity e){
    em.merge(e);
}
```

When I do this, the merge never executes and the operation just hangs. Turning on trace logging for Hibernate didn't reveal anything that would indicate a problem. Is there anything I can do to prevent Hibernate from locking the table when it's not actively modifying it?

Comment: Get a thread dump to find out what is 'stuck' and where exactly, and turn SQL logging on so you can see what is executed that might cause a lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a transaction was staying open from the getEntity call because the service gets injected into an overarching EJB. When putting @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) the other transaction was never closed and therefore the merge could never get to open a new transaction. By putting @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED) on the getEntity method when it was being called that connection wouldn't be considered in the transaction. That way when the merge method would be called the container would be free to open up a new transaction just for the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from MySQL (which uses REPEATABLE_READ), the default isolation level of most relational database systems is READ_COMMITTED. All databases allow you to set the default transaction isolation level.

You can experiment with READ_UNCOMMITTED to bypass the long-running update issue. With Hibernate, it means setting:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">1</property>
```